# Iterator producing unique random numbers in a specified range

Tags: java, random, iterator

I needed an iterator that produced random numbers, never repeating them, in a specified range of 0..max-1 (index for a collection). When the numbers are exhausted it should not have a next anymore.

The simplest way might be to shuffle an ArrayList and make an iterator. But in typical usage, I will want only 4-5 unique random numbers, from a total in the region of 100. So shuffle seemed too CPU-heavy. And here is the class I came up with. It is written in Java 8 (the requirement of version 8 is acceptable in my case).

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NonRepeatingRandom implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private List<Integer> unused;
    private Random random;

    public NonRepeatingRandom(int max) {
        unused = IntStream.range(0, max).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return ( unused.size() > 0 );
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        int size = unused.size();
        if ( size==0 ) {
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
        }
        int idx = random.nextInt(size);
        int result = unused.get(idx);
        unused.remove(idx);
        return result;
    }

}
```

I would appreciate comments on this code.

Comment: I would add random numbers to a `Set`, check if there are enough in it and crate the iterator from the set...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle this would lead to repeated generation of randoms until they are not in the set. Definitely a no.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik generating a random number from `Random` is like 10-20 instructions the probability of a retry in the case @Paparazzi said is 5% then a second retry is 0.25%, the infinite sum of retries is bounded by 6% performance cost which is less than 1 extra instruction on average.

Comment: This works fine while the probability is low, but creates a very high cost for fringe cases when all numbers except a few have been used up. A modified version is being discussed below one of he answers: use a DIY pseudorandom generator that is *supposed* to be non-repeating until it has looped fully, then use a HashSet as a safety check.

Comment: Wow all that code, when all you need is shuffle and take the top few elements of the shuffled array, because "shuffle seemed too CPU heavy" on 100 elements? I'm always confused why future readability and maintainability is often given such low priority over minor performance considerations

Comment: @BradThomas A shuffle is not necessarily less code or more readable.

Comment: @BradThomas I'd need an iterator over the shuffled array, anyway. An index loop would not work as well.

Comment: @Paparazzi Collections.shuffle() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks pretty reasonable. Just a few minor issues:

> ```
>     public NonRepeatingRandom(int max) {
> ```

That's fine for general-purpose use, but you should consider adding a constructor which takes `(int, Random)` for testing purposes.

---

> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean hasNext() {
>         return ( unused.size() > 0 );
>     }
> ```

I generally recommend favouring `isEmpty()` over `size() == 0`. For many collections `isEmpty()` just calls `size()`, but for some it is much more efficient, so it's a good habit to always use `isEmpty()`.

---

> ```
>         int idx = random.nextInt(size);
>         int result = unused.get(idx);
>         unused.remove(idx);
> ```

This is the biggest problem, although for your typical use case it might be relatively minor because it doesn't sound like this iterator is going to be a bottleneck.

Removing a random element from a list takes \$O(n)\$ time. But since you don't care about the order of the elements in the list, you could copy the last element to position `idx` and then delete the last element in \$O(1)\$ time.

Comment: Well, if I did not care about performance at all I'd just use a shuffled list to make an iterator automatically. And I was not aware that removing a random element was expensive. So what is the right way to remove one in my case? `unused.set(idx,unused.get(size-1)); unused.remove(size-1);` ?

Comment: @MikhailRamendik, if you remove a random element from an `ArrayList` then it has to copy everything after that element to the previous index, taking linear time on average; and if you remove a random element from a `LinkedList` then it takes linear time on average to find the correct node. The code in your comment is correct.

Comment: Don't need to remove at all.  Just copy and decrement the index to the list by 1.

Comment: @Paparazzi, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by `decrement the index to the list by 1`, but I think it involves adding a field to the iterator and changing the implementation of `hasNext()` as well as `next()`. Removing the element from the list is an elegant way of tracking how many elements have not yet been returned.

Comment: OK remove is elegant.  Not as efficient as just decrement an index so last is no longer considered.

Comment: I went with removing the last element so that `unused` keeps its meaning. A trade-off between efficiency and clarity.

Comment: But unused can keep the same meaning and just be based on the index.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I'm kind of gleaning from your code and description that you want to visit all numbers in the range \$[0,n]\$ in a (pseudo) random order without visiting any number twice. I'm saying pseudo random here because you are using `Random` which is just a pseudo random generator.

You can use something called a [Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). This is a type of well known pseudo random number generator, in fact [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is an LCG.

Funny thing about LCGs is that they have a period and if you choose your constants suitably you can pick that period and guarantee that you will not have any repeats in the period, the PRNG is said to have a [full period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_cycle).

The general form of the algorithm is: $$x_{k+1} = (a*x_k+c) \%n$$ where \$0<n\$ and \$0<a,c<n\$. The value of \$x_0\$ is simply chosen as a seed value.

If \$n\$ and \$c\$ are [co-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), \$a-1\$ is evenly divisible by all prime factors of \$n\$ and \$a-1\$ is evenly divisible by 4 if \$n\$ is divisible by 4. Then the LCG will have a full period.

I did a test [here](https://ideone.com/yuoRNK). I was a bit sneaky: to make sure \$c\$ and \$n\$ are coprime, I simply picked \$c\$ to be a very large prime. In fact if you pick \$c\$ as a prime number such that \$c\$ > \$\text{INT_MAX}/2\$ then \$c\$ and \$n\$ will always be co-prime unless \$c=n\$ in which case simply have two such \$c\$ values that you pick between. To make \$a-1\$  evenly divisible by all the prime factors of \$n\$ and 4 if \$n\$ is divisible by 4, I simply pick \$a=n+1\$.

**Note that these values do not fulfill the conditions as listed on Wikipedia: \$0<a,c<n\$.** However they seem to work just fine. So consider it a word of caution to either check up the maths yourself to see if this is OK or to use a more robust way of selecting \$a\$ and \$c\$.

At any rate using an LCG will be the most efficient in terms of memory and computation provided that you can choose the coefficients easily.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea in principle, but I am definitely not enough of a mathematician to rely on a DIY implementation of a pseudorandom generator *and* expect it to not repeat without a safety check, probably in the form of a set. The safety check would negate the performance gain.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik Actually if you use a `HashSet` the safety check will be \$O(1)\$  time which is faster than your current code which is \$O(n)\$ due to the call to `remove()`. The memory requirement will still be the same at \$O(n)\$. So it's still better than what you have now :)

Comment: Upon re-reading the description I don't  even understand what "m" is supposed to be... really not enough of a mathematician - it's probably obvious to a professional?

Comment: @MikhailRamendik Oops sorry my bad, I kind of switched from \$n\$ to \$m\$ in the middle without noticing. I've fixed it.

Comment: ...but now n has two meanings (max and index of x) and I'm not sure which is which in the formula?

Comment: @mikhailramendik fixed that, apparently not having a notation day

Comment: This type of solution always produces the sequence since the range is baked into seed requirements.  Randomly calculating a new 'c' for each run will be expensive (unless there's a some way to do it I'm not familiar with).

Comment: @tedbigham you get a new sequence by picking a new arbitrary x0. You don't need to calculate C, just pick a large enough prime number and you're good to go.

Comment: @EmilyL changing x0 only shifts the returned values up or down, it doesn't change the sequence order.

Comment: @TedBigham LCGs are a class of PRNGs and as such the sequence will change if you pick a new **random** starting seed. Yes, sequences from nearby seeds may only differ slightly, but you don't increment the seed between sequences, you pick a new, random one. Please compare the outputs of https://ideone.com/yuoRNK and https://ideone.com/NbfR2n with different seeds. See the links in the answer to learn more about how LCG based PRNGs work. If you want larger difference between nearby seeds, chose a larger value of "a". This values chosen are "weak" for a PRNG but it provides the properties desired.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36120/emily-l Perhaps you should look at the sequences generated by https://ideone.com/yuoRNK and https://ideone.com/NbfR2n a little more closely. They are the same “sequence” just offset by the difference between your two chosen values for x.  Since n is 30 and you are modding by n, there are only 30 unique datasets you can generate for any given value of c, and they all have the same base sequence. Notice that x=3124 generates the same dataset as x=3154.

Comment: @TedBigham LCGs make no promise that all the possible sequences of numbers can be obtained, in fact in general they cannot. OP never specified that strong randomness was a requirement, rather they wanted something computationally fast. Which is what this answer provides, a PSEUDO random shuffle, it has flaws for sure but it that might not matter as the properties for the randomness weren't specified. If you want more "randomness" pick a new C for every run from a list of large primes you can get from the internet and hard code it in. Or if n is always small, use a sieve to generate primes.

Comment: OP wants something not "CPU heavy" yet this solution requires calculating a new C every time, which is very CPU intensive, or being limited to literally the same sequence of numbers every time.

Comment: Hardcode a list of "large" primes and pick one at random or iterate through them. It's not CPU nor memory intensive.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to speed / efficiency the `remove(idx);` is the weakness.

Use `hasNext()` in checking for the Next exception.

A couple options:

1. Don't create the list up front. Use a HashSet to track used numbers. Call random and check the HashSet for used numbers. If you are only producing a small fraction of the range then this is the most efficient. Even producing 1/3 the range this is most efficient (from my experience).  Can enhance with reduce the range if you produce the first or last. For this in [C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162072/random-range-with-no-repeat-and-efficient-for-small-subset).
2. Create the List but track the index.  Based on random produce the number and then copy the last active value (index) in the List to the random.  Then index--.  Use index as the range for the random and for any left.  This removes the call to `remove(idx);`.

   ```
   public class NonRepeatingRandom implements Iterator<Integer> {    

   private List<Integer> unused;
   private Random random;
   private Integer size;

   public NonRepeatingRandom(int max) {
       unused = IntStream.range(0, max).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
       random = new Random();
       size = max;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
       return ( size > 0 );
   }

   @Override
   public Integer next() {
       if ( !hasNext() ) {
           throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
       }
       int idx = random.nextInt(size);
       int result = unused.get(idx);
       unused[idx] = unused[size-1];
       size--;
       return result;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: With respect to `unused[idx] = unused[size-1];`, has Java added C#-style indexers?